# Text missing unless in header tag

Tags: html

Here is my website at the moment.

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/LEVENDIZ/dHTdk/2/>
```

There is text that can not be viewed. If i move the div inside the header tag it shows up on screen, when only in the body it does not.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#maintext` would need a top margin of 160px (the height of the header) because the header position is `fixed` and thus is positioned relative to the viewport (the browser window) the other content is not affected at all by the `<header>` and therefore appears on the page as though it does not even exist.

Here's a good basic explanation of the differences in positioning: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: How do i go about editing this in? I added margin-top:160px; to the css but it hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dHTdk/3/ Although, I would point out that generally, fixed elements tend to make for poor usability- they make poor use of smaller devices or screens and frequently break designs. Personally, I shy away from them.

Comment: Thank you, do you have some information on how i would change the element to be dynamic?

Comment: Dynamic in what way? So that it scrolls with the page? If that is what you are looking to do, using the default static positioning would likely be the better option.

Comment: I'm not sure if dynamic is the correct turn but something that won't make for poor use with smaller devices/screens.

Comment: I would start looking into making it responsive- start working on some tutorials working with media queries that way your site can look best across most devices (phones, tablets, and desktop)

Comment: Thanks, I'll do so now!